# Retain Key Order in Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, database

I want to keep keys order in mongodb strictly as its defined in schema.
I am using mongodb 3.0.14 and mongoose 3.9.7 . As in Mongoose >=4.6.4 retainKeyOrder property is working to maintain key order.
[More Detail](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#retainKeyOrder)

How i can achieve this earlier version of mongoose.